# "Self-Recursive" AppData folder causing RoboCopy to freak out

Tags: batch-file, windows-7-x64, robocopy

I use RoboCopy to perform a daily backup script using Windows batch.
about a week ago I noticed that RoboCopy detects one path as "too long" [see att. image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSbhb.png)

Obviously, this folder path does not exist. But for some reason I have an **"Application Data"** system folder inside my **AppData\Local**, which is a shortcut to itself (i.e the *AppData\Local* path).

This seems to be what is causing RoboCopy to interpret a folder path as AppData\Local\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\ etc

- My questions are:

  1. How could this system folder have appeared?
  2. Is it safe to simply remove the "faulty" folder link?

Comment: It's not "faulty", it is supposed to be there.  It's an application compatibility measure.  Generally speaking when copying the user folders you want the `/xj` option, to exclude junction points.

Comment: thanks, I do believe your answer would suffice as a proper answer tho I will experiment a little bit before marking this question as solved